# How to convert String to DateTime in dart?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple card which code is like this

```
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // need to show date here 
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          height: Width * 0.12,
                          width: Width * 0.12,
                          child: Image.asset('images/Group 3@3x.png')),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Width * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              width: Width * 0.76,
                              child: Text(
                                data['items'][i]['start']['address']
                                    .toString(),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: Height * 0.015,
                          ),
                          Container(
                              width: Width * 0.76,
                              child: Text(
                                  data['items'][i]['end']['address']
                                      .toString(),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                  )))
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
```

I need to show Date and time, my issue is that I have date and time in String type.

like this  `"dateStart": "2021-01-01T02:55:39.000Z"`

How can I show this string as date and time ? I simply want it like Time : 02:55, Date: 2021-01-01

Answer (score -1):

```
      String  dateStart = "2021-01-01T02:55:39.000Z";
      DateTime input = DateTime.parse(dateStart);
      String date = 'Date: ${input.year}-${input.month}-${input.day}';
      String time = 'Time : ${input.hour}:${input.minute}';
```